# Fedora 22 - compile - __atomic_is_lock_free

Tags: c++, gcc, boost, fedora

I am try to compile a software (SuperCollider) on Fedora 22 but I run into a problem:

```
libsupernova.a(server.cpp.o): In function `std::atomic<boost::lockfree::detail::tagged_index>::is_lock_free() const':
/usr/include/c++/5.1.1/atomic:212: undefined reference to `__atomic_is_lock_free'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
server/supernova/CMakeFiles/supernova.dir/build.make:96: recipe for target 'server/supernova/supernova' failed
make[2]: *** [server/supernova/supernova] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:3383: recipe for target 'server/supernova/CMakeFiles/supernova.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [server/supernova/CMakeFiles/supernova.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:146: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

It seems to me that this is a problem with libatomic. Is it possible that gcc does not link to libatomic?

Does someone have any idea on how to solve this problem?

Another idea would be to try to install -latomic, but I cannot find information about.
Instead I already installed libatomic. I don't know if they are the same.

Comment: After ./Configure  ... edit Makefile find  and change the line the line: CNF_EX_LIBS=-pthread to CNF_EX_LIBS="-pthread -latomic

Answer (score 7, accepted):

i ran into the same issue, and yes you do need to link libatomic. the way to do this is to add to the line: `set(CMAKE_CXX_LINK_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_LINK_FLAGS} -latomic")` to the top level CMakeLists.txt file before running cmake.

the full flow might look like this:

- `git clone https://github.com/supercollider/supercollider.git`
- `cd supercollider`
- add `set(CMAKE_CXX_LINK_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_LINK_FLAGS} -latomic")` to top level CMakeLists.txt
- run `ccmake .` to configure the install
- `mkdir _build ; cd _build`
- `cmake ..`
- `make && <sudo> make install`

you may or may not need sudo depending on where you have decided to install supercollider.

Answer (score 5):

> It seems to me that this is a problem with libatomic. Is it possible that gcc does not link to libatomic?

It only links to libatomic if you tell it to.

> Does someone have any idea on how to solve this problem?

Link to libatomic.

> Another idea would be to try to install -latomic, but I cannot find information about. Instead I already installed libatomic. I don't know if they are the same.

You can't "install -latomic" because `-latomic` is the compiler/linker option that says to link to libatomic, and you can't "install a linker option" because it's an option to a program, not a package.

You install libatomic, then you link to it with `-latomic`

(Aside: I hope to fix GCC so that you won't need to use `-latomic` explicitly for simple cases, only more complex ones, see https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=65913)

Comment: This is a good news.. I was indeed searching for how to link libatomic to gcc. Would you please tell me how to do it or where to find information about?

Comment: I don't understand the question, didn't I already answer that? **You install libatomic, then you link to it with `-latomic`**. Install it with `dnf install libatomic` then use `-latomic` when linking.

Comment: Sorry, but it is not so clear to me. I  installed libatomic. Now I am stuck.

Comment: I mean: how do you link things?

Comment: Use `-latomic` when building SuperCollider. To get CMake to do that I think you want something like `TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(atomic)`