# clang++: atomic does not link

Tags: c++, clang, atomic, stdatomic

```
// http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic/is_lock_free

#include <iostream>
#include <utility>
#include <atomic>

struct A { int a[100]; };
struct B { int x, y; };
int main()
{
    std::cout << std::boolalpha
              << "std::atomic<A> is lock free? "
              << std::atomic<A>{}.is_lock_free() << '\n'
              << "std::atomic<B> is lock free? "
              << std::atomic<B>{}.is_lock_free() << '\n';
}
```

What magic compiler or linker flag needs to be added to solve this issue?

```
$ clang++ --version
Apple LLVM version 10.0.0 (clang-1000.10.44.4)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin18.2.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin

$ clang++ -o atomic atomic.cpp -std=c++14 -O2 -Wall -pedantic -lpthread
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "___atomic_is_lock_free", referenced from:
     _main in atomic-e3a97a.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

**Edit (2019.01.16):** even -latomic doesn't work

```
$ make atomic
$ clang++ -o atomic atomic.cpp -std=c++14 -O2 -Wall -pedantic -lpthread -latomic
ld: library not found for -latomic
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Comment: add `-latomic` to your linker flags. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31381892/fedora-22-compile-atomic-is-lock-free)

Comment: "ld: library not found for -latomic"  You haven't got libatomic installed or there is some search path issue preventing clang from finding it.  The function you are missing in that library.  From this file: https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/master/libatomic/glfree.c

Comment: Where is libatomic.so on a Mac (10.12.3), XCode 8.2.1, Build version 8C1002?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/45346246/2836621

Comment: It seems clang compiles only when `is_lock_free()` returns true…

Comment: @YongweiWu Because when a type is lock free, clang can optimize the build by generating builtin CPU instructions for the atomic operations rather than relying on an external library.