# clang doesn't support atomic::is_lock_free for types larger than 32 bits?

Tags: c++, compilation, locking, size, atomic

I've got the following:

```
struct A { int a[4]; };
struct B { int x, y; };
int main()
{
    std::cout << std::boolalpha
            << "std::atomic<A> is lock free? "
            << std::atomic<A>{}.is_lock_free() << '\n'
            << "std::atomic<B> is lock free? "
            << std::atomic<B>{}.is_lock_free() << '\n';
}
```

It compiles and works well, but if I raise the size of A:

```
struct A { int a[5]; };
struct B { int x, y; };
int main()
{
    std::cout << std::boolalpha
            << "std::atomic<A> is lock free? "
            << std::atomic<A>{}.is_lock_free() << '\n'
            << "std::atomic<B> is lock free? "
            << std::atomic<B>{}.is_lock_free() << '\n';
}
```

Well clang gives error:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
"___atomic_is_lock_free", referenced from:
    _main in atomics.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

What kind of error is this? Does it require extra library for "is_lock_free" to work with bigger structures?

---

Problem fixed, use "-latomic" linking flag!

Comment: This seems like an implementation bug. Both code samples are perfectly valid C++

Comment: I used g++4.8.5, same error:

Comment: /tmp/ccvfzqdw.o: In function `std::atomic<A>::is_lock_free() const':
1.cpp:(.text._ZNKSt6atomicI1AE12is_lock_freeEv[_ZNKSt6atomicI1AE12is_lock_freeEv]+0x17): undefined reference to `__atomic_is_lock_free'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Comment: Post your solution as an answer, so it may help others.